Double pendulum with symplectic Runge-Kutta option for NDSolve not working
I would like to use the Symplectic Partitioned Runge-Kutta integrator from Mathematica to solve the nonlinear double pendulum equations.
I set up the problem by first calculating the Hamiltonian function as
$$
H(p,q) = p^T M^{-1} p + V,
$$
where $M$ is the system mass matrix and $V$ is the potential energy.
Then, the first order motion equations are obtained by calculating
$$
\dot p=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q};\quad \dot q=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}.
$$
NDSolve works very well with its automatic settings. However, when using the SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta method, it simply fails. Here are the warnings:
NDSolve::sprksep: The Hamiltonian of the differential system in the method SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta does not appear to be in separable form. Try using the method ImplicitRungeKutta with coefficients ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients.

NDSolve::initf: The initialization of the method NDSolve`SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta failed.

Here is the code
(*mass matrix*)
M = {{(m1 + m2) l1^2, 
    m2*l1*l2*Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]]}, {m2*l1*l2*Cos[q1[t] - q2[t]], 
    m2*l2^2}};

(*motion variables*)
p = {p1[t], p2[t]};
q = {q1[t], q2[t]};
variables = Join[p, q];

(*gravity potential*)    
V = -m1*g*l1*Cos[q1[t]] - m2*g (l1*Cos[q1[t]] + l2*Cos[q2[t]]);

(*Hamiltonian*)
H = 1/2 p . Inverse[M] . p + V;

(*canonical equations*)
equations = Join[-Grad[H, q], Grad[H, p]];
diffEquations = 
  Table[equations[[i]] == D[variables[[i]], t], {i, 4}];

(*parameters*)
{m1, m2, g} = {1, 1, 9.81};
\[Omega]0 = 2 \[Pi];(*pseudo-pulsation*)
l = 
 g/\[Omega]0^2;(*from \[Omega]0=Sqrt[g/l]*)
l1 = l2 = l;

(*initial conditions*)    
initial = {p1[0] == 0., p2[0] == 0., q1[0] == Pi/4, q2[0] == Pi/2};

(*simulation length*)
tMax = 10;

(*NDSolve "automatic" solution*)
solAuto = First[
  NDSolve[{diffEquations, initial}, variables, {t, 0, tMax}
   ]
  ]

(*NDSolve SPRK solution*)
solSymp = First[
  NDSolve[{diffEquations, initial}, variables, {t, 0, tMax},
   Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, "PositionVariables" -> q}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/10
   ]
  ]

Note that the SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta method from NDSolve works very well with the linearized version of this system. I find this quite strange. What am I doing wrong?

SPRK works for separatable case, H = T(p) + V(q, t), the part with mass matrix is not sovable

you can still use SPRK with this 'trick' or just go implicit (sorry for formatting): List["FixedStep",Rule[Method,List["ImplicitRungeKutta",Rule["DifferenceOrder",10],Rule["Coefficients","ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients"],Rule["ImplicitSolver",List["Newton",Rule[AccuracyGoal,MachinePrecision],Rule[PrecisionGoal,MachinePrecision],Rule["IterationSafetyFactor",1]]]]]]

@I.M. On your first comment: it is something that I fail to see. The first term on the first equation in my question is clearly "T(p)" (kinetic energy). The second one corresponds to "V(q,t)". Why is it then that this symplectic integrator does not work on such a simple case, that any other implicit integrator handles perfectly well? About your second comment: where do I incorporate the code? Within the Method option of NDSolve?

@Meclassic, your kinetic energy is not $T(p)$ but $T(p, q)$, since it explicitly depends on $q$. Hence, $H$ is not separable. See also Zymplectic project or Symplectic Methods for Double Pendulum.


Why should it? Your $T$ is a (nonlinear) function of $qs$ and $ps$, but WM requires just $T(p)$. You might be also interested in this tutorial 2) use it as Method , it is symplectic


@I.M. Okay, I just realized the meaning of your comment. $M\equiv M(q)$... By this logic, what I understand is that the SPRK method can be applied to a few cases only.
